# SQL Query with one column and multiple LIKEs

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, subquery

I got a table with a column which contains content like Driver||Helper||Garden. I want to export this table to a new system, where I have diffrent columns for each user Skill (as it should be).

Question: How can I get this kind of information in a nice SQL export.

```
SELECT user_id, driver, helper, garden FROM `ujc72_comprofiler` WHERE cb_erfahrungen LIKE "%Driver%"
```

Gives me the users with a certain skill, but I want multiple columns for one user for my export.

Comment: FYI: _"where I have diffrent columns for each user Skill"_ is not _"as it should be"_; what it should be is most likely a separate table with about two columns, one referencing the user and the other listing (or referencing) a skill the user has; each user record having _0 to many_ records in this `user_skills` table.  ...though separate columns is still a step up from what you apparently have now.

Comment: This is one awful sounding schema

Comment: What is the structure of ujc72_comprofiler? Where is cb_erfahrungen located??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string. So,it will divide Driver|Helper|Garden to separate Driver, Helper and Garder columns.

This function is absent in mysql. You have to create it your own.
Check this link: https://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

---

Also, you may work with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function:

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
        -> 'www.mysql'
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
        -> 'mysql.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this query: `select column_name, column_name, column_name from table_name where column_name like '%driver%'`. I think this what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding this difficult in SQL because the select-list of columns must be fixed at the time you prepare the query. There is no feature of SQL that allows the number of columns in the result set to be expanded automatically to fit the patterns found in your data.

So don't try to do this with SQL. Write a script to run a simple SQL query, then split the string in your script code.

Virtually any language has a function to easily split a string into an array.

Use the right tool for the job.